# how to control transaction when i create a new thead in java?

Tags: java, transactions

I created a new thread on service level, and I invoke a method of service in the run method of the new thread. The code is like:

```
public void run() {          
    businessService.dealCheckThirdPay(pageNumber,date);   
}
```

I note an annotation on `dealCheckThirdPay` method
`@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`,but eclipse alert me i must use 'try catch' on `businessService.dealCheckThirdPay(pageNumber,date)` method. i think if i use 'try catch' i cant rollback transaction. How can I deal with it?

Comment: First, what makes you think that your new `Thread` will pay attention to `@Transactional` - I'm going to assume that you're using an AOP based transactional framework; such as Spring. In which case, it will rollback the transaction _inside_ `dealCheckThirdPay` _then_ rethrow whatever `Exception` caused the rollback. How you handle this `Exception` outside the transaction is orthogonal to how the framework handles transactional rollback.

Comment: yea,i use spring to handle business logic code. i solved the problem. i can catch the exception and throw new runtimeException.its ok. runtimeException can rollback transaction. other Exceptions cant.

Comment: thanks for your help.